# Cannot use await in Portable Class Library for Win 8 and Win Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, async-await, windows-store-apps, portable-class-library

I'm attempting to create a Portable Class Library in Visual Studio 2012 to be used for a Windows 8 Store app and a Windows Phone 8 app.

I'm getting the following error:

> 'await' requires that the type
>   'Windows.Foundation.IAsyncOperation'
>   have a suitable GetAwaiter method. Are you missing a using directive
>   for 'System'?

At this line of code:

```
StorageFolder guidesInstallFolder = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync(guidesFolder);
```

My Portable Class Library is targeted at .NET Framework 4.5, Windows Phone 8 and .NET for Windows Store apps.

I don't get this error for this line of code in a pure Windows Phone 8 project, and I don't get it in a Windows Store app either so I don't understand why it won't work in my PCL.

The GetAwaiter is an extension method in the class WindowsRuntimeSystemExtensions which is in System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll. Using the Object Browser I can see this dll is available in the *.NET for Windows Store apps* component set and in the *Windows Phone 8* component set but not in the *.NET Portable Subset*. I just don't understand why it wouldn't be in the Portable Subset if it's available in both my targeted platforms.

Comment: Does it work if you remove .NET Framework 4.5 as a target and keep only WP8 and Windows Store?

Comment: Actually you can't remove the .NET Framework 4.5, when you try to it says: _italic the following framework will be selected automatically because they support all the available functionality that is portable between the other frameworks you have selected: .NET Framework 4.5_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the Async targetting pack [on NuGet here](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async) for async/await to work for that combination of targets.

UPDATE:

Try this (nonsense) code snippet to check if it is using async/await correctly.

```
public async void MyMethodAsync()
{
    var req = WebRequest.Create("");
    await req.GetRequestStreamAsync();
}
```

However even if you get past the first problem of `async/await` not being available, the  `Package` API you are calling is not available in the PCL.

Comment: Actually I've already tried that and it didn't help. Not surprised though as that packages is for .NET 4 and Win Phone 7.5, I'm trying to use .NET 4.5 and Win Phone 8

Comment: That doesn't matter for async/await, but you'll hit another error as I've just found. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Paul your code snippet compiled just fine, I'm noticing that the GetRequestStreamAsync() function is in the AsyncExtensions class found in the Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll, this dll appears to have come from the Async targeting pack you originally suggested. So perhaps I can somehow re-write my code so that it does not require the GetAwaiter() method that it is currently trying to use?

Comment: Paul I also find that this line of code compiles for me: _Package myPackage = Package.Current;_

Comment: That line doesn't work for me: I get `error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Package' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` in a clean PCL C# library targeting WP8 and Windows Store. Are you doing anything special to try and look this up?

Comment: OK, I now see that I have three references in my PCL, .NET Portable Subset, Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.Extensions and a third just called Windows. I have two NuGet packages installed, one is the package you have suggested and the other is the same one except one version earlier [here](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.NotBeta)

Comment: I just set out to discover how I got the reference to _Windows_, as this is not available normally. It appears I may have found it using the object browser, by selecting the _Windows Phone SDK 8.0_ component set, from there, there is a button that will _Add to References in Selected Project_ I must have done this. It is this reference that allows me to use StorageFolder and Package, so although it may now compile I'm not confident it will run on my targeted platforms. Will let you know as soon as I get a change to try it.

Comment: I suspect this is why you can get `Package.Current` to compile, but I can't. However that's not going to work for a PCL library and I think this is probably the root cause of your question.

Answer (score 1):

> I just don't understand why it wouldn't be in the Portable Subset if it's available in both my targeted platforms.

The portable subset is not just everything that's common. Every member of the PCL is there deliberately, and there are a good number of members not included.

If a profile is missing something you need, request Microsoft to add it (via MSConnect or on the Q&A tab of the [old-but-still-monitored PCL page](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b0e0b5e9-e138-410b-ad10-00cb3caf4981)).