# How do I await a Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient.GetAsync()? Getting Intellisense error

Tags: c#, asynchronous, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1-universal

*Edit: I am already using the Microsoft.Bcl.Async nuget package in my project, but the error persists.*

I am writing an asnyc "make sure the URL is accessible" method using the following code:

```
public async Task<ConnectivityMonitorResult> TestModeUrlCheck(string url)
{
    try
    {
        var filter = new HttpBaseProtocolFilter();
        filter.IgnorableServerCertificateErrors.Add(Windows.Security.Cryptography.Certificates.ChainValidationResult.Expired);
        filter.IgnorableServerCertificateErrors.Add(Windows.Security.Cryptography.Certificates.ChainValidationResult.Untrusted);
        filter.IgnorableServerCertificateErrors.Add(Windows.Security.Cryptography.Certificates.ChainValidationResult.InvalidName);

        using (var httpClient = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient(filter))
        {
            var resp = await httpClient.GetAsync(new Uri(url), Windows.Web.Http.HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);

            if (resp.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                return new ConnectivityMonitorResult(ConnectivityType.Connected);
            else
                return new ConnectivityMonitorResult(ConnectivityType.NotConnected);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return new ConnectivityMonitorResult(ConnectivityType.NotConnected, "Unhandled error: " + ex.Message);
    }   
}
```

This method will be for the "Test Mode" of my app. (The production Check method will fail with bad SSL certs). It will be hitting local dev servers with self-signed certs.

Problem is that this code won't build because of the following error on the `var resp = await` line:

> 'IAsyncOperationWithProgress' does
>   not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and the best extension
>   method overload 'AwaitExtensions.GetAwaiter(Task)' requires a receiver
>   of type 'Task'

I have not been able to figure how to properly construct the GetAsync() call to get this to work.

**Update**

This is for a Windows 8 app using the portable class libraries. I am using await in other places in the project. And I have the `Microsoft.Bcl` and `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` Nuget packages already added to my project.

**Update**

I tried updating the code to this:

```
public async Task<ConnectivityMonitorResult> TestModeUrlCheck(string url)
{
    try
    {
        var filter = new HttpBaseProtocolFilter();
        filter.IgnorableServerCertificateErrors.Add(Windows.Security.Cryptography.Certificates.ChainValidationResult.Expired);
        filter.IgnorableServerCertificateErrors.Add(Windows.Security.Cryptography.Certificates.ChainValidationResult.Untrusted);
        filter.IgnorableServerCertificateErrors.Add(Windows.Security.Cryptography.Certificates.ChainValidationResult.InvalidName);

        using (var httpClient = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient(filter))
        {
            var resp = await Test(httpClient, url);

            if (resp.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                return new ConnectivityMonitorResult(ConnectivityType.Connected);
            else
                return new ConnectivityMonitorResult(ConnectivityType.NotConnected);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return new ConnectivityMonitorResult(ConnectivityType.NotConnected, "Unhandled error: " + ex.Message);
    }   
}

private async Task<Windows.Web.Http.HttpResponseMessage> Test(Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient client, string apiUrl)
{
    var asyncOp = client.GetAsync(new Uri(apiUrl), Windows.Web.Http.HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
    return await Task.Run(() => asyncOp.GetResults());
}
```

It compiled, but I got the runtime error:

> WinRT information: A method was called at an unexpected time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot use await in Portable Class Library for Win 8 and Win Phone 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13896760/cannot-use-await-in-portable-class-library-for-win-8-and-win-phone-8)

Comment: Please refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13896760/cannot-use-await-in-portable-class-library-for-win-8-and-win-phone-8) question.

Comment: @AndreyAshikhmin I am using await in a number of other places in the project.

Comment: Yes, but do you use await on `IAsyncOperationWithProgress` in those other places, or on `Task`?  Later might work without problem, but for await work on `IAsyncOperationWithProgress` it has to have `GetAwaiter()` method. In Windows 8.1 and later it implemented as an extension method in System namespace, but apparantelly, Win8 doesn't have it.

Comment: @AndreyAshikhmin Ah, I see. I will check on this.

Comment: @AndreyAshikhmin I did already have Microsoft.Bcl.Async packages added to my project.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133308/discussion-between-andrey-ashikhmin-and-jwatts1980).

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by updating the target of the project. The other projects in the solution were targeting Windows8.1, whereas this one was targeting Windows8. When I updated the target, the errors went away and the app built and ran.